# Scrollable ResultSet JDBC Postgresql

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, resultset

When I create a prepared statement like this in java (using JDBC):

```
pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
```

everything works ok. However when I want a scrollable resultset and use this:

```
pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(qry,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
```

I get a syntax error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"
```

I'm not even using RETURNING in my query.

Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Update:**
It seems to work if I use this:

```
pStmt = db.prepareStatement(qry,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

What is the difference between SENSITIVE and INSENSITIVE?

Thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to post the query? If so, please do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter to prepareStatement should be one of Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS or Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS.

I guess you want to use

```
PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql,
                                   int resultSetType,
                                   int resultSetConcurrency)
```

Comment: Ahh method overloading at its best :)

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE : This assumes that the result set does not “sense” database changes that occurred after execution of the query.

ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE : picks up changes in the database that occurred after execution of the query